# Oracle ODI : Collect stats on C$ table

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

Is there a way to perform collect stats on C$ tables (Loading Tables) in ODI? The challenge is, since C$ table name is dynamic hence at the runtime it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Statistics on the `C$` tables are usually gathered by the Loading Knowledge Module.

For example, the `LKM SQL to Oracle` Knowledge Module has an `Analyze work table` task which runs `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` referencing the `C$` table with the `odiRef.getTableName("COLL_SHORT_NAME")` substitution API (documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/integrate.1111/e12645/odiref_reference.htm#ODIKD1307)).

Comment: Thanks Marco for the advise. It worked for me :)